# Liveagent: Getting the details was not successful

Tags: liveagent, operators, custom-service-console

I have two Operators in my LiveAgent.

When Operator 2 is on line and Operator 1 is offline all works fine: the calls arrrives to the Operator 2 and the Transcript and another custome object are saved.

When Operator 1 is online and Operator 2 is offline the chat starts correctly with the Operator 1, but after the chat in a pop-up I get the error:

> Getting the details was not successful

[image]

Why?

Comment: It looks like you're using a VF page for your operators. How is the VF page getting these details? Can you share the relevant code?